# How to execute targets of build.xml from an executable (ex)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, eclipse

My project is running successfully in eclipse after creating executable, if I double click on project It's running through command prompt also I am able to execute with TestNG and after completion of execution without execution of targets program execution is completing.

Comment: Unclear, what is issue???

Comment: I have created a project in eclipse of ant when i execute from  eclipse build.xml is executing successfully.After that i have  exported the project as runable jar file when i run from command prompt as java -jar example.jar code  is executing  but targets in build.xml are not execuitng

Comment: your jar should missing something. Export it again as runnable jar and try.

Comment: i have tried so many times but same is happening

Comment: I have done same and it is working here.

Comment: can you say the procedure how you have created jar file and how you have executed from command line it would help me

Comment: Right click on project -> export -> Runnable JAR file then next-next till last step. I run that from cmd same as you told.

Comment: when i run as java -jar example.jar then in command prompt it is displaying Testng :command line suite---------------------------------------command line suite total test run:4,skips:0,failures:0-----------------------and the program execution is stopping

Comment: When you run is manually from eclipse then it is working?

Comment: Also please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393223/how-to-create-a-executable-jar-file-for-testng-and-the-runnnig-point-should-be-t

Comment: yes when i am running from eclipse i am able to execute targets and generate xslt reports also